# How to make full-text search on activities show the same results to admins and regular CiviCRM editors?

Tags: activities, search-results, admin

Using the full-text search to find one word, as an admin I get some results but with with my test account (no admin privileges) I don't see any. This is a word that so far only appears in the "Subject" and "Details" fields of a couple of activities. Is there a permission I have missed to enable or is this a bug?

More details (added later):

- With the same test account, using "Find Activities" and introducing the same word, the query shows search results correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Can your test user see the details of those activities?

Comment: Yes, with my test account I can see the activity with all its content, including the word I'm searching for. In our instance, CRM editors have the permission "CiviCRM: view all contacts" enabled, which includes the ability to see activities.

Comment: I have added more details to the description. "Find Activities" shows the correct results to the same user that gets no results with "Full-text Search".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "view all activities" permission. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/fe68d8eea3ffaa1d495bfe2563b755897b1759b6/ext/legacycustomsearches/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/FullText/Activity.php#L32

Comment: Correct! This solved the problem. Thank you so much. We didn't have this permission enabled because CRM editors already were accessing activities without problems, so we thought that this permission would be "embedded" in one of the permissions already granted.